# Anaconda Jupyter is not opening by cmd and Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, windows-10, jupyter

My Jupyter lab/notebook not opening by cmd or anaconda navigator in windows 10.
I tried to unistall and install toolkit, and update all anaconda and python. but it won't works.
It always gives AttributeError

while installing `importlib_metadata` it gives:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\shant\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter-1.0.0.dist-info\METADATA'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jupyter lab write jupyter notebook.

Comment: not any jupyter launching either Lab or Notebook it gives same error

Answer (score 0):

What does the cmd shell tell when you type `jupyter --version`? For instance, my shell tells, that I do not have jupyter lab installed:

`jupyter lab      : not installed`

Comment: jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.5
ipython          : 7.16.1
ipykernel        : 5.3.3
jupyter client   : 6.1.6
jupyter lab      : 2.1.5

Comment: I already installed Jupyter, and also tried to unsinstall then install jupyter but it gives continuesly same error.